# Проверить input value на null

Tags: javascript, html

Что в этом коде не правильно?

```
if(markaPlace.value != null){
    modelPlace.removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В инпуте **всегда** строка. Когда нет значения - **пустая строка**. `null` там не может быть по определению. Соответственно надо проверять на пустую строку, видимо

Comment: if(markaPlace.value != ""){
    modelPlace.removeAttribute('disabled');
}
вместе null  ковычки написать?

Comment: Да. Ещё можно `markaPlace.value.trim() != ''`   так как в инпуте могут быть пробелы или tab.. и возможно это тоже захочется принимать за пустую строку

Answer (score 0):

в данном кейсе я бы использовал объект [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

```js
if(!Boolean(markaPlace.value)){
    modelPlace.removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```